# Filtering a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have nested list like below :-

```
 list = [['A:1','B:(null)','C:3','D:4'],
        ['A:1','B:abc','C:6','D:7'],
        ['A:1','B:def','C:2','G:44','E: 600','F: 6600'],
        ['A:1','B:ghi','C:33','D:44']]
```

I want to convert it into a data frame in such a way that anything `before :` will be the `column name` and `after :` will be the value

Here i am having two types of data one is :-

```
[['A:1','B:(null)','C:3','D:4'],
  ['A:1','B:abc','C:6','D:7'],
  ['A:1','B:ghi','C:33','D:44']]
```

and one item is different which is

```
['A:1','B:def','C:2','G:44','E: 600','F: 6600']
```

Expected output:-

df1 =

[image]

and df2 =

[image]

Q.1) As of now i am having just two kind of data so i want two data frame.
Q.2) can we make this dynamic so that it will create multiple dfs as per the items in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, 1st convert your `list` to `list` of `dict` (also do not name your list as list, it will overwrite the python function ), 2nd create the dataframe ,using `isnull` with `dot` create the group key , then build the dict , I do not recommend create the dataframe dynamically , you can put them into the `dict` , if that is matter look at `local`

```
[dict(tuple(y.split(":")) for y in x )for x in l] # make you list to list of dict 
Out[11]: 
[{'A': '1', 'B': '(null)', 'C': '3', 'D': '4'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': 'abc', 'C': '6', 'D': '7'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': 'def', 'C': '2', 'E': ' 600', 'F': ' 6600', 'G': '44'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': 'ghi', 'C': '33', 'D': '44'}]
newl=[dict(tuple(y.split(":")) for y in x )for x in l]
pd.DataFrame(newl)
Out[13]: 
   A       B   C    D     E      F    G
0  1  (null)   3    4   NaN    NaN  NaN
1  1     abc   6    7   NaN    NaN  NaN
2  1     def   2  NaN   600   6600   44
3  1     ghi  33   44   NaN    NaN  NaN
newdf=pd.DataFrame(newl)
s=newdf.isnull().dot(newdf.columns)# using dot create the groupby key 
s
Out[16]: 
0    EFG
1    EFG
2      D
3    EFG
dtype: object
```

---

```
{x: y for x , y  in newdf.groupby(s)}# using group by create the dict 
Out[17]: 
{'D':    A    B  C    D     E      F   G
 2  1  def  2  NaN   600   6600  44, 'EFG':    A       B   C   D    E    F    G
 0  1  (null)   3   4  NaN  NaN  NaN
 1  1     abc   6   7  NaN  NaN  NaN
 3  1     ghi  33  44  NaN  NaN  NaN}
d={x: y for x , y  in newdf.groupby(s)}
d['D'].dropna(1,thresh=1)
# result can using dict selection
# dropna here means atleast one column should have at least one not null value , 
# if it is all null , then we drop the entire columns  
Out[19]: 
   A    B  C    E      F   G
2  1  def  2  600   6600  44

d['EFG'].dropna(1,thresh=1)
Out[21]: 
   A       B   C   D
0  1  (null)   3   4
1  1     abc   6   7
3  1     ghi  33  44
```

---

Not recommend `local`

```
d={x: y.dropna(1,thresh=1) for x , y  in newdf.groupby(s)}
variables = locals()
for i,j in enumerate(d.values()):
    variables["df{0}".format(i+1)] = j
df1
Out[26]: 
   A    B  C     E      F   G
2  1  def  2   600   6600  44
df2
Out[27]: 
   A       B   C   D
0  1  (null)   3   4
1  1     abc   6   7
3  1     ghi  33  44
```

Comment: wooh.... i mean that worked man. thanks a lot... I don't know why some people just downvote the question when they don't get it.... thanks a lot man

Comment: @ak333 this is a good question :-) worth for re-check in the future :-)

Comment: @PatrickArtner i tried a lot of ways but by using lambda expressions and i always got stuck somewhere. I was doing the very hard by going step by step. I am sorry if i hurt your feelings. I was looking for something dynamic.

Comment: @W-B thanks for the comment. I am trying to parse the command line outputs for voice log analysis and its pain in the ass. to do that because the original programmer have written some shitty code for output.

Comment: @PatrickArtner i am new to stackoverflow. I will surely keep this in my mind in future. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. create dicts from your list (I opted to replace `"(null)"` by `None`)
2. group `dict`s  by sorted keys via `collections.defaultdict`
3. create and yield dataframes from the groups

---

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

# convert to dictionaries        
def makeDict(inner): 
    return {k: (v if v!= "(null)" else None) for k,v in (p.split(":") for p in inner)}

# group and yield dfs
def makeIt(l):
    # collect data as dicts
    dicts = []
    for inner in l:
        dicts.append( makeDict(inner))

    # group by sorted keys
    t = defaultdict(list)
    for d in dicts:
        t[tuple(sorted(d.keys()))].append(d)

    # create dataframes from groups and yield them
    for k in t:
        df = pd.DataFrame(t[k])
        yield df
```

Usage:

```
l = [['A:1','B:(null)','C:3','D:4'],
     ['A:1','B:abc','C:6','D:7'],
     ['A:1','B:def','C:2','G:44','E: 600','F: 6600'],
     ['A:1','B:ghi','C:33','D:44']]

dfs = list(makeIt(l))

for df in dfs:
    print("-"*20)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
--------------------
   A     B   C   D
0  1  None   3   4
1  1   abc   6   7
2  1   ghi  33  44

--------------------
   A    B  C     E      F   G
0  1  def  2   600   6600  44
```

Comment: thanks for teh answer but when i am executing dfs = list(makeIt(l)) ... i am getting an error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Nevermind it worked out.. one small question . How i can assign names to those dataframes. so that i can call as of now its just printing those.

Comment: @ak333 they are inside a list, you can use `dfs[0]`, ... ,`dfs[len(dfs)-1]` to get the single dfs out - you can decompose the list into variables if you know how many are in it: `df1,df2,df3,df4 = dfs` (if dfs contains 4 lists) etc - normal list rules apply. You can `for df in dfs:` and then iterativly use them like I did for printing ...

Comment: @ak333 update for you using local , but not recommend

Comment: Why not remomended..It could cause any issue.